# What's wrong with my usage of grep?

Tags: linux, shell, grep, tr

I'm executing the following command:

```
echo "ze2s hihi" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep 'h*'
```

but instead of getting `hihi` in the output I'm getting this:

```
ze2s
hihi
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is:

```
echo "ze2s hihi" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep 'h.*'
```

With "h*" you are asking to match any number of h's in a sequence, including 0 h's, which ze2s matches.

Or maybe you just want to match anything which contains an h:

```
echo "ze2s hihi" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep 'h'
```

Comment: I replaced `h*` with `h+` but it's still not working

Comment: That's because + is one of the special symbols that either needs to be escaped 'h\+' or use the -E flag: grep -E 'h+'

Comment: s/special symbols/ERE metacharacters/. There is nothing "special" (and nothing "new") in software. The OP needs `grep 'h.+'` or `grep 'h'`, not `grep 'h.*'` since that would just match the same strings as the more concise `grep 'h'`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `egrep` or `grep -E` if you only want to have the lines with `h*` at the beginning:

```
echo "ze2s hihi" | tr ' ' '\n' | egrep '^h'
```

Answer (score 2):

The asterisk matches the preceding item zero or more times. Thus `h*` matches `h` *zero* or more times, i.e. anything.

If you want to match `h` and any characters after it, use `h.*` expression, where the period matches any single character.

Answer (score 1):

You got the answer to your question but FYI you don't need multiple commands and pipes to do what you want:

```
$ echo "ze2s hihi" | awk -v RS='\\s+' '/h/'
hihi
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS and `\s` for space chars.